# VBScript: Finding the number of non-null elements in an array

Tags: vbscript

What is the "best" way to determine the number of elements in an array in VBScript?

UBound() tells you how many slots have been allocated for the array, but not how many are filled--depending on the situation, those may or may not be the same numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off there is no predefined identifier called `vbUndefined` as the currently accepted answer appears to imply.  That code only works when there is not an `Option Explicit` at the top of the script.  If you are not yet using `Option Explicit` then start doing so, it will save you all manner of grief.

The value you could use in place of `vbUndefined` is `Empty`, e.g.,:-

```
If arr(x) = Empty Then ...
```

`Empty` is a predefined identify and is the default value of a variable or array element that has not yet had a value assigned to it.

However there is Gotcha to watch out for.  The following statements all display true:-

```
MsgBox 0 = Empty
MsgBox "" = Empty
MsgBox CDate("30 Dec 1899") = True
```

Hence if you expect any of these values to be a valid defined value of an array element then comparing to Empty doesn't cut it.

If you really want to be sure that the element is truely "undefined" that is "empty" use the `IsEmpty` function:-

```
If IsEmpty(arr(x)) Then
```

`IsEmpty` will only return true if the parameter it actually properly `Empty`.

There is also another issue, `Null` is a possible value that can be held in an array or variable.  However:-

```
MsgBox Null = Empty
```

Is a runtime error, "invalid use of null" and :-

```
MsgBox IsEmpty(Null)
```

is false.  So you need to decide if `Null` means undefined or is a valid value.  If `Null` also means undefined you need your `If` statement to look like:-

```
 If IsEmpty(arr(x)) Or IsNull(arr(x)) Then ....
```

You might be able to waive this if you know a `Null` will never be assigned into the array.

Comment: Your comment is great and all, except it has absolutely nothing to do with OP's original question, and did nothing but waste 5 minutes of my time and god only knows how many days worth of other peoples time who've stumbled upon this question.The question wasnt how to determine if an array was empty, or the nuances between the Empty property, it was to determine how many elements were in an array. I have no clue why you're posting an answer to comment on another answer you perceived as incorrect, while omitting an answer to OP's question in your own.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a non-iterative method to do this, so here's the iterative method:

```
Function countEmptySlots(arr)
    Dim x, c
    c = 0
    For x = 0 To ubound(arr)
        If arr(x) = vbUndefined Then c = c + 1
    Next
    countEmptySlots = c
End Function
```

As Spencer Ruport says, it's probably better to keep track yourself to begin with.

Comment: This actually gets the opposite of what I wanted, but the technique works just as well the other way around (looking for filled slots, comparing arr(x) <> vbUndefined).

Comment: See the answer provided by AnthonyWJones for a more comprehensive solution.

Comment: For the sake of posterity I'm changing the selected answer to the one given by AnthonyWJones.  (Thank you, Chris.)

Comment: Don't use `for x = 0`. There's a perfectly good `LBound(arr)` function for that.

Comment: @Nyerguds, I have never encountered a situation in which `LBound(arr)` would return a non-zero value. When would this happen?

Comment: @Chris Nielsen: Sorry, I'd been programming in pascal too much. That language actually has variable array start indices.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built in to tell you what elements are filled. The best way is to keep track of this yourself using a count variable as you add/remove elements from the array.